# iOS UIScrollView with Voice Over

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, accessibility

I am relatively new to iOS development and struggling with an issue with `UIScollView` in Voice Over mode.

I have a `UIScollView` and a set of `WebViews` that are shown in the scroll view. The scrolling works perfectly with the swipe in normal mode. When I turn on the VoiceOver, I expected it to work in the same way with the three finger swipe gesture, but it is not responding or scrolling.

I have a `xib` file and this `ScrollView` is added to the `xib` and have custom controller class which adds multiple webviews to the `ScrollView`

Please let me know if I am missing something very basic.

Comment: If I set 'self.webViewWrapper.isAccessibilityElement = YES;' on the Scroll View the three finger swipe is working in Voice Over but the contained WebView is not accessible any more.

Comment: Found out that both parent and child cannot be accessible at the same time.
In my case UIScrollView is the parent and just acting as container and WebViews are the children. It is not a good idea to make containers accessible and if the WebViews are accessible my UIScrollView cannot be accessible at the same time. I need to provide a paging control or something like navigation to make it accessible.